# how to change dotNetOpenAuth GoogleAddressBook sample to retrieve more than 25 contacts?

Tags: .net, gdata-api, dotnetopenauth, google-contacts-api

How do you suggest I proceed in changing the GoogleAddressBook sample to retrieve > 25 contacts?

Google suggests using AutoPaging=true on http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#retrieving_without_query

If this is still valid, how can I go about passing this parameter in the DotNetOpenAuth sample provided?

Answer (score 0):

The AutoPaging property is just that: a property.  It isn't a query parameter, and this property isn't available unless you're using the Google .NET library (which to my knowledge doesn't use OAuth).

The [latest version of the protocol documentation for Google Contacts](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#retrieving_without_query) states:

> Note: The feed may not contain all of the user's contacts, because there's a default limit on the number of results returned. For more information, see the max-results query parameter in [Retrieving contacts using query parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#retrieving_with_query).

[Another documentation page](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/reference.html) explains that there is also a `start-index` parameter, so you can still retrieve blocks of contacts at a time if you so choose.

So it looks like all you need to do is add `?max-results=500` or some other high number to the request you send out.  I've [updated the DotNetOpenAuth sample](http://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/commit/7932f4eb87228ee9c5c1b6090a52cae79b898552) to make this easy.